# Finding the length of circumference using distance between points?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

if a sphere is there and two points $(x, y)$ , $(x+dx, y+dy)$ lie on it [$dx, dy$ are infinitesimally small]

Now the straight line distance between the two points is $$ds=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)}$$ 
using the techinques of integration how can we find the circumference of a circle on the sphere?

the circle's diameter should be equal to the diameter of the sphere.

I saw on my book using $\oint$, but i didn't understand the after process he did!

he did something like this

$$\oint ds= \oint \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$$

$$\implies LHS=2\int ^{+R}_{-R}dx\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} $$

i didn't understand this step and i even don't know how to proceed from this point.

Comment: "He did something like this".. Did the author do _exactly_ what you typed, or was it something _similar_? Because it's kind of important.

Comment: @Mattos yes here is the pic i.stack.imgur.com/S7kXG.png

Comment: Is it a sphere or a circle? (usual coordinates for sphere are x,y,z)

Comment: sorry for replying late. It is a sphere but we have to find the equation of greater circle(which is 2-D)